# Use of UITabBarController within a UIVisualEffectView programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, tvos

I'm currently learning about Swift and UIKit as I'm trying to make a tvOS app.
I am trying to stay away from Storyboards and so I'm doing this with just code.

I think this is more of a code design question though.

Let's say I have an OverlayVC class, derived from UIViewController (It's a VC which is presented modally on top of some existing context). That class has a redefined loadView method where I instantiate my own OverlayView class, which derives from UIView. I'm trying to strictly separate the View from the View controller.
Now, in that OverlayView constructor, I instantiate a UIVisualEffectView, and set the constraints so that it takes the entire frame. The goal is to make something appear on top of the existing context with a blur effect.

So far so good, when the OverlayView is being presented, I get everything blurry.

Now, I want to have a tab bar controller inside this, so I want to make a class that derives from UITabBarController and instantiate it in my OverlayView.
But I need to give a View to the UIVisualEffectView through its contentView attribute.
The easy way for me to do this would be to instantiate my TabBarVC within the OverlayView class. But I feel like it doesn't belong there, but should instead be held within the OverlayVC class. Problem is that the UIVisualEffectView is instantiated in the OverlayView, not the VC, so setting its contentView in the VC isn't straightforward.

I've been turning this around in my head a few times and can't actually figure out what is the proper class design for this.

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks !

Below is a simplified snippet of how I have done this right now:

```swift
class TabBarViewController: UITabBarController {

    convenience init() {
        self.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        
        let vc1 = ViewController1()
        let vc2 = ViewController2()
        self.viewControllers = [vc1, vc2]
    }
}

class OverlayView: UIView {
    
    let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .regular))
    let dimmingView = UIView()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.backgroundColor = .clear
        self.clearsContextBeforeDrawing = false
        self.isOpaque = false
        
        blurView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(blurView)
        
        dimmingView.backgroundColor = .black
        dimmingView.alpha = 0.75
        dimmingView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(dimmingView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            blurView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor),
            blurView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor),
            blurView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor),
            blurView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 750),
        ])
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            dimmingView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor),
            dimmingView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor),
            dimmingView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blurView.bottomAnchor),
            dimmingView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor),
        ])
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

class OverlayViewController: UIViewController {
    
    convenience init() {
        self.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        self.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let tabBarController = TabBarViewController()
        addChild(tabBarController)
        tabBarController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        (view as! OverlayView).blurView.contentView.addSubview(tabBarController.view)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            tabBarController.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            tabBarController.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            tabBarController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            tabBarController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
        ])
        
        tabBarController.didMove(toParent: self)
    }

    override func loadView() {
        view = OverlayView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    }
}
```

So, here I have a clear split between the Overlay view and its View controller. The OverlayView class contains everything related to the content of the view and all the constraints for Auto Layout, which makes the OverlayViewController class free from any stuff related to the view itself, except for one thing: the constraints for the tab bar controller, which I can only set in the OverlayViewController because the OverlayViewController instantiates the TabBarController, and so I don't have access to the TabBarController view in the constructor of the OverlayView class. This is basically what annoys me here, as the constraints should, strictly speaking, be a View thing, not a ViewController thing, yet I can only set those in the ViewController, unless I've missed something.

Comment: OverlayView is a "View" and A Viewcontroller has no business in a view. So really you've already kinda answered your own question on design. I would suggest posting some code and maybe some images of what you're trying to achieve. That way more experienced developers might be able to point you in the proper direction. It sounds to me like you may be relying too much on view controllers when what you are trying to do is show visuals ie: view

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @SeaSpell I've just edited the question to include my current code and explain what I don't like with it (although it does work).